# C# AccessViolationException when call c++

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport, access-violation

I am trying to call a function of a C++ library. On result there is a AccessViolationException, but i do not have any other details.

How can I get more details on the error?

Here there is my code. Thanks

#### This is the section where I declare the functions

```cs
[DllImport("library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr getResult();
   
public delegate Result CallbackDelegate();
```

#### This is the code where I call the methods

```cs
IntPtr ptr = getResult();
CallbackDelegate callback = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<CallbackDelegate>(ptr);
Result result = callback();
```

Comment: [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer): *"ptr is converted to a delegate that invokes the unmanaged method using the __stdcall calling convention on Windows, or the __cdecl calling convention on Linux and macOS. You can set the calling convention by applying the UnmanagedFunctionPointerAttribute to the delegate."*

Comment: You set the calling convention on the `getResult` import, but not on the pointer you receive. You could use a C# 9.0 function pointer, instead. The syntax is (arguably) cleaner and you wouldn't need `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer`.

Comment: Hi, tks for the reply. Do you have an example with c# 9.0 function pointer?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/function-pointers).